# I get drawing artifacts when drawing onto a transparent xcb window. How do I fix this?

Tags: xorg, xcb

[image: Illustratory image]

I am trying to create transparent windows with xcb and have the transparency information be provided by a compositor.

I have succeeded in creating transparent windows, and drawing to them with cairo, however, my problem should be self-explanatory in the image I provided.
For some reason, I am getting artifacts in the second window from the first window. I don't know how to fix this exactly.

Here's the lua code I am using:

```lua
local init_x = 80
local init_y = 280
local init_width = 300
local init_height = 200

local win_id = swin.create(init_x, init_y, init_width, init_height)
local pix_id = spixmap.create(init_width, init_height)

local surf = scairo.create_from_pixmap(pix_id, init_width, init_height)
local lsurf = lgi.cairo.Surface(surf, true)
local cr = lgi.cairo.Context(lsurf)

-- the source operator should use data from the compositor
cr:set_operator(lgi.cairo.Operator.SOURCE)
-- paint the window transparent. 
cr:paint_with_alpha(0.0)

cr:rectangle(0, 0, 40, 40)
cr:set_source_rgb(0.8, 0.1, 0.8)
cr:fill()

swin.map(win_id)
spixmap.draw_portion_to_window(pix_id, win_id, 0, 0, init_width, init_height)
```

The lua code is obviously a simplification of the C code, but nonetheless, I don't think I am doing anything wrong.

I would add more details, but I don't want to pollute the post. If you want to know something, ask, and I will edit my post.

Comment: Sorry, but your Lua code does not help me that much. I tried googling for this Lua library you are working on, but didn't find anything. So here is another idea: Does your library somehow provide access to a cairo surface for the window in question (result of e.g. `cairo_xcb_surface_create()`)? If so, could you use `cairo_surface_write_to_png()` to get a screenshot of the window and check if the artifacts are also present there?

Comment: Another idea would be to use a screenshotting tool for this. Experimenting with `xtrace import foo.png` suggests that this uses GetImage directly on the window I clicked on and not using anything that might come from the compositing manager. Are the artifacts already present here? (I am trying to figure out whether this might be introduced by the compositing manager or not)

Comment: Also: Welcome to why AwesomeWM has `--no-argb`. In a perfect world, that option doesn't do anything. In the reality, this works around performance problems and driver bugs in X11.

Comment: If that is Lua, please add an according tag, it improves visibility! Also, if possible, provide a [mcve]!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could it be that you are seeing garbage from uninitialised memory? Specifically, when you send a `CreatePixmap` request, the X11 server just allocates memory, but does not initialise it in any way.

I have to admit I do not quite understand what your Lua code is doing, but the following comment raised a red flag:

```lua
-- paint the window transparent. 
cr:paint_with_alpha(0.0)
```

The comment suggests that you think that makes the cairo surface completely transparent (fills everything with alpha=0). But instead, this line just does not do anything at all.

To clear a cairo surface to transparent, you want:

```lua
cr:set_operator(lgi.cairo.Operator.CLEAR)
cr:paint()
```

Comment: I seem to have gotten it to work by using the `CLEAR` operator and then just doing `cr:paint()` with no alpha. Is that the same thing, or no?

Comment: Yup, CLEAR is equivalent to SOURCE with a clear source (all pixels (0, 0, 0, 0)). Sorry for forgetting about CLEAR before.

Comment: Ok, nice then I would consider the problem solved. I would edit your post to use the CLEAR operator, but it doesn't let me edit it. If you could, that would be nice.